Is it possible that fetching data from Redis cache sometimes takes longer than our previous response times due to memory constraints on my PC?
Is it possible that sometimes fetching redis cache data also takes more time than out last resposnses time due to memory in my PC?

When getting Redis cached data in a PC, the difference in response time can be affected by a variety of factors，such as Redis server load, Network latency, BigKeys and so on. So the time may be longer or shorter.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

If you don't set maxmemory in redis.conf and you use all the memory you have, Redis will happily use up swap space as well. So, you'll want to set maxmemory.
And while you're at it, you'll probably want to set an eviction policy too. There are several to chose from:

volatile-lru: Evict using approximated LRU, only keys with an expire set.
allkeys-lru: Evict any key using approximated LRU.
volatile-lfu: Evict using approximated LFU, only keys with an expire set.
allkeys-lfu: Evict any key using approximated LFU.
volatile-random: Remove a random key having an expire set.
allkeys-random: Remove a random key, any key.
volatile-ttl: Remove the key with the nearest expire time (minor TTL).
noeviction: Don't evict anything, just return an error on write operations.

